# Get non-matching characters from regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to get whatever characters not matching the regex. E.g. "abc123" would return "123", `[1,2,3]` or something similar.

Is there any built in way to achieve this?

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){

    var valid = /^[a-zA-Z\s*]*$/.test(this.value);
    console.log(valid);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JrWZ/

Another solution in case someone is intrested:

```
var x = this.value.split('').filter(function(v){
    return !/[a-zA-Z\s*]+/.test(v);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var result = "abc123def123".split(/[a-zA-Z\s*]+/).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return curr ? (prev.push(curr), prev) : prev;
}, []);
```

If you want the result as a string

```
var result = "abc123def123".split(/[a-zA-Z\s*]+/).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return curr ? prev + curr : prev;
}, "");
```

Comment: @Johan Thanks :) I updated my answer with `reduce` variant as well :) Please check

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `reduce` :) Is there a way to make it either return a string or an array with each "invalid" character as an element? I know I can just to a `result[0]`, but jsut curious. Oh and another tip: use `[]` rather than `new Array()` imo.

Comment: @Johan Please check the answer now. This version returns a `string`

Comment: I added another solution. Feel free to add it to your answer so I can remove it from my question.

Comment: @Johan You can write that like this `var result = "abc123def123".split(/[a-zA-Z\s*]+/).filter(function(data) {
    return data ? data : false;
}, "");
` :)

Comment: Right, I keep forgetting about the pattern argument in `split()` :D

Comment: @Johan Anyway, good attempt at `filter`. :) Learn the functional programming aspects of javascript well. They will be interesting.

Comment: A small comment on your suggestion though: you might as well `return data`. Also, you're example return an array with one element, while mine returns an array of characters.

Comment: Your `reduce` merely rewrites its argument and can be safely omitted: `result = input.split(regex)`

Answer (score 1):

```
/[^abc]+/.exec('abc123')
```

Returns the characters when they do not match either a, b or c.

Answer (score 0):

how does this work with returning not accepted characters separated by comma?
reduce will not work in below example
example:

```
const allowedSplChars = /^([a-zA-Z0-9@\-._]{3,50})$/;
let allowedCharacters = allowedSplChars.test(uidInput.value);
var disallowedCharacters = [];
disallowedCharacters = uidInput.value.match(allowedSplChars);

if (allowedCharacters) {
  let splCharErrorNode = document.getElementById("uid_splCharacters");
  if (splCharErrorNode) {
    uidValidationcontainer.removeChild(splCharErrorNode);
  }
} else {
  //remove duplicates
  disallowedCharacters = disallowedCharacters.filter((element, index) => {
    return disallowedCharacters.indexOf(element) === index;
  });

  let splCharErrorNode = document.getElementById("uid_splCharacters");
  if (splCharErrorNode) {
    splCharErrorNode.innerHTML = `${disallowedCharacters.join(", ")}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: @thefourtheye , reduce does not work on string cahracters example *, %, how to extract all non matchings character list , not satifying regex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).